# How to Email "content of route direction between source to destination using bing Map" as body of email

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I am using Wpf and c#. In bing map, I had got the direction of the routes from source to destination in a scrollviewer using following code.

Instruction is a scrollviewer Name.

```
Instructions.Content = directionsManager.RouteSummaryView;
```

Now I want to bring the content of routes direction as body of email when email this to a specific ID. Means user can get the direction of a specific route by sending email to his email id.

I am well aware with the code to send email, just want to know Is there any way through which i can get this direction of routes in string or something like so that i can email that.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the same question on the Bing Maps forums, but said Windows Store app there rather than WPF. Since the WPF map control doesn't have a RouteSummeryView I will assume you meant Windows Store app here.

In a Windows Store app all the content is XAML which won't render in emails. What you can do is convert the RouteSummaryView to an image and then pass that image to the email. I wrote a blog post on how to do this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/05/01/how-to-save-and-share-map-screenshots-in-windows-store-apps-net.aspx

Comment: thanks it was about window store app, actually i used a scrollviewer, so snapshot will not work, because scrollviewer need to scroll to access complete direction content. So it there any other possibility????

Comment: You should still be able to do this with a scrollviewer. The blog post I linked to puts the route summery in a scroll viewer and it still works fine.

Comment: Thanks about your kind help @rbrundritt, but actually problem is that screenshot cover the portion of scrollview, which is visible, And the content which will be visible after scroll down, is cant be capture through snapshot, So thats the issue, how to take screenshot of complete content of route information, which is displayed by scroll Viewer.

Comment: Look that that blog post I linked to. It captures the full list of instructions from the scroll viewer, even when things are out of view.

Comment: i i did try that link already, okay i will try once more, and let you know about, anyways thanks alot for your answer and time.